# Get a part of the image from TextureView

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

I am using the code for cameras from [Android Developers Samples](http://developer.android.com/samples/Camera2Basic/) to get a part of the image while in preview and perform some processing on it.

I want to get a square image from [0,0] to [99,99] of the preview, process it and show it in an ImageView on the fly. I tried getting the current image by entering the following code:

```
final Activity activity = getActivity();
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    final Bitmap originalBitmap = mTextureView.getBitmap();
    // more code here
 }
});
```

[at this part of the code](http://developer.android.com/samples/Camera2Basic/src/com.example.android.camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.html#l287). By calling getBitmap(), it made the application extremely slow.

Is there an efficient way to get the square part I need in 1:1 ratio?

I know I can call getBitmap() with a smaller size and make it faster but I want to avoid losing data.

Comment: Don't run on ui thread. Use `new Thread(new Runnable{...})`. Or asynctask as well

Comment: @v-kalyuzhnyu : By doing so I get the following error _android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views._ when accessing the mTextureView.

Answer (score 2):

Whats for about this?

```
CustomView mTextureView = new CustomView(getApplicationContext());
new Task().execute(mTextureView.getBitmap());
```

and this is asynctask

```
 public class Task extends AsyncTask<Bitmap, Void, Void> {

    public Task() {

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Bitmap... objects) {
        //... do stuff
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
   }
}
```